# JAVA 6 Docker client

Tags: java, docker, client, java-6, orchestration

I'm looking for a way to orchestrate Docker containers using JAVA 6. So I have the Docker images ready but I want to be able to start and stop and interact with them but I am limited to JAVA 6.

All the JAVA client libraries I've found so far instead of JAVA 7, but I can't use that yet.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVen though the java docker-clients compile with jdk7, you can try and [change the **`target`** of `maven-compiler-plugin` to 1.6](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), and see if that is compatible.

See [`spotify/docker-client/pom.xml`#L199](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/blob/e3b8d300b9420e313794251b5c0d7e7fa2aaa363/pom.xml#L199) or [`docker-java/docker-java/pom.xml`#L233](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/be5c1c3a45afb0f76bb981ccafc236fd08e05a72/pom.xml#L233)

You would still compile with jdk 1.7, but the end result should be able to execute in a JDK6 environment (unless the sources depends on some specific 1.7 feature)